# In $\Delta ABC, AB = AC = \sqrt{3}$ and $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $AD = 1$ . Find $(BD\times DC)$ .

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In $\Delta ABC, AB = AC = \sqrt{3}$ and $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $AD = 1$ . Find $(BD \times DC)$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I have no idea for this problem. From the picture if $D$ lies a bit near of $B$ then I just reflect it to get $E$ near $C$ , $\Delta ADE$ is an isosceles triangle, but there's no use to it, how would that help in the original problem?

In fact, that did not look like the case when I tried it in Geogebra. $D$ lies nearly in the middle of $BC$ and, also with a bit of approximation, I got $(BD\times DC)$ to be nearly equal to $2$ , but why?

Can anyone help me with a reason here? Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $BC = 2x$. Say altitude from $A$ to $BC$ is $h$ and meets $BC$ at point $M$.

Given isosceles triangle,

$BM = MC = x$.

$h^2 = (\sqrt3)^2 - x^2 = 3 - x^2$

$DM = \sqrt {1- h^2} \,$

WLOG, assuming $D$ is left of $M$

$BD = BM - DM = x - \sqrt {1 - h^2}$

$CD = CM + DM = x + \sqrt {1 - h^2}$

$BD.DC = x^2 - 1 + h^2 = 2$

Comment: Nice solution , how did you get the idea?

Comment: It was my typo sorry :0 .

Comment: @Anonymous I just felt Pythagoras may just do it so tried and it worked.

Comment: +1 elegant...,,

Comment: @user2661923 thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Draw $AH\perp BC$

$$AH^2+DH^2=1$$

$$AH^2+BH^2=AH^2+(BD+DH)^2=AH^2+BD^2+DH^2+2\times BD\times  DH=3$$

$$BD^2+2\times BD\times DH=BD(BD+2\times DH)=BD(BD+DE)=BD\times BE=BD\times DC=2$$

where $BD=EC$ and $BE=DC$